# c++ eclipse odd compiler error messages

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am getting extremely weird errors in my code. On the line where the function is declared, it says that string is not a part of std, and that 'variable ‘SDL_Texture loadImage’ has initializer but incomplete type'. On the line after that, it says that it expected a ; before the curly brace. This same snippet of code was literally working a minute ago. What can I do to fix it? If you need any more information, I will gladly give it. Also, I am running on Linux, so that might make a difference, too.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "LevelRenderer.h"
#include "err_log.h"

SDL_Texture loadImage(std::string path)
{
    return loadTexture(getResourcePath() + path + ".png", getLevelScreen());
}
```

Comment: "Irrational compiler messages" are there for a reason; compilers are much more rational than you or I.

Comment: And where do you include `<string>`? Without that header file, there is indeed no such thing as `std::string`.

Comment: Taking a stab in the dark here, but you probably want to return a pointer to a Texture rather than the Texture itself ( Just from my experience with working with SDL ).

Answer (score 2):

It means you haven't included the header that defines `SDL_Texture`; only one that declares it. That makes it *incomplete* and you can only do limited things with it. In particular, you can't create an instance of it, as this function does when it returns by value.

According to my [google skills](http://fossies.org/dox/SDL2-2.0.3/structSDL__Texture.html), you need to include `<SDL_sysrender.h>`.

You should also include `<string>` since you're using `std::string`. That may be the cause of the second error; but even if one of the other headers happens to include it for you, it's better not to rely on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. It still gave me the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

One, you forgot `#include <string>`.

Two, `loadTexture` returns a pointer, so you want

```
SDL_Texture* loadImage(std::string path)
{
    return loadTexture(getResourcePath() + path + ".png", getLevelScreen());
}
```